# Vim - how to replace with match without last char?

Tags: vim, replace

I would like to fix every line in code which has following pattern:

```
int main() {
```

with

```
int main()
{
```

Same applies for if statements and loops. Simply said - fixing brackets. I have matched them with:

```
:%s/.*\(.*\).*{/&^?^M{/gc
```

But I get the following output:

```
int main() {
{
```

How do I replace my pattern with it's match (&), but without the last character or specifically without the "{" ?

Comment: This may be of help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35206/replace-using-vim-reuse-part-of-the-search-pattern

Comment: It could work, but using \1 freezes my vim 7.4 on ubuntu 16.04LTS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%s/.*(.\{-})[^{]*\zs{/\r&/
```

this command works for your example, add flag `g` or `gc` if you need them. however you may want to check if the indentation also correct if you apply it on you real source file.

I think there should be special tool for the code style fixing.. you should check it. IMO, Vim/shell script  would be the last option for those source codes batch editing.

Comment: It worked like a charm, thank you. There aren't many source files in the project, but you are right about the tool.